# How to block all similar events in case 2 when first of them was triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/9c4xG/

```
$('.container').on('change.namespace focusout.namespace', '.item', function(event) {
    $('<p>', {
        'text': 'event: ' + event.type   
    }).appendTo('.container');
});
```

case 1: If you press tab when focused in input - triggered one event (focusout);
case 2: If you type any word in input and press tab - triggered two events (focusout, change);

How to block all similar events in case 2 when first of them was triggered.

Is there a universal way to use only one of these events (focusout, change, ..) if triggered more than one? And disable others for namespace or current handler.

Sorry, foolish-anglish.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `return false`

Comment: @f00bar I can't get any of them to work with his JSFiddle. Is it because they are both specified in the same `.on()`?

Comment: For a text field, aren't `change` and `focusout` the same, essentially? Why not just use focus out and check for a value? To elaborate: the `change()` event is not triggered until the element loses focus

Comment: Chris Rockwell, its for example

Answer (score 1):

Using a flag as a semaphore ...

```
$('YourInput').on('events',function(e) {
    var t = $(this), data = t.data('flag') || false;
    if (data) {
        return;
    }
    // Locking semaphore
    t.data('flag', true);
    // Your code here
    // Free semaphore
    t.data('flag', false);
});
```

Comment: Its disable all event, but i need only current namespace or handler. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only way is to handle this yourself:

```
$('selector').on('events', function() {
    if ($(this).data('handling-event')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).data('handling-event', true);
    .... code here ....
    $(this).data('handling-event', null);
});
```